# Implementing Dependency injection static methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

In this old code I am trying to update , they implemented dependency injection like this:

```
public class Program
{
    private IProgramRepository programRepository;

     public Program(IProgramRepository repository)
        {
             this.programRepository = repository;
        }

     public Program() : this(new EN_Program()) { }
```

now in this program class all methods are static, so all of the static methods all actually have 2 methods like this:

```
    public static List<Program> GetProgramsByUser(int userId)
    {
        return GetProgramsByUser(userId, GetDefaultRepository());
    }
    private static List<Program> GetProgramsByUser(int userId, IProgramRepository repo)
    {
        return repo.GetProgramsByUser(userId);
    }
```

Now I've read this among other things about implementing DI:

> This is not dependency injection at all. This actually clearly violate
>   the dependency inversion principle. The principle say that "High level
>   module should not depend upon the low level module, both should depend
>   on abstraction. Details should depends upon abstraction". In above
>   code Product.cs itself create EN_Program object. So it directly
>   depends on IProgramRepository implementation (EN_Program). If in future
>   another implementation comes of IProgramRepository interface then Product.cs
>   code itself need to change. So it is probed that it is not proper way
>   to do.

It looks like the old developers wanted to implement DI just starting with the helper classes (Program.cs) with nothing injected into the controllers.

Am I correct in assuming that this old code was not written correctly ?  Is it necessary when implementing DI that everything from the controller to the back end have injections?

ex.  The controller would need to be injected with an Interface that the helper class uses (Program.cs) - then Program.cs is injected with an interface that the repository uses

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comment is incorrect. It talks about Dependency Injection pattern, but it quotes the [Dependency Inversion Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle). The overloaded constructor is an implementation of the Dependency Injection **pattern**, and the default constructor is an implementation of the [Poor Man's Dependency Injection anti-pattern](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/07/03/how-not-to-do-dependency-injection-in-nerddinner/).

Although the overloaded constructor practices the Dependency Injection pattern, the default constructor does not and does in fact violates the Dependency Inversion **Principle**. Because of the reasons quoted.

So you're absolutely practicing Dependency Injection, but you are also practicing Poor Man's Dependency Injection which is bad for a lot of reasons. For instance:

- Your code takes a direct dependency on a low level component disallowing you to ship them separately.
- The direct dependency makes it harder to swap implementations, which is something that is very common to do when you add cross-cutting concerns (using decorators or interceptors) . You don't want to go through the whole application to change all constructors just to wrap `EN_Program` instances with a decorator or interceptor.

Comment: @Scott Selby Adding to the great writing of @Steven, if you want to avoid providing a dependency each time you want to get a `Program` instance (or always getting `Program` instances through DI containers), you can use a [Service Locator](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html#ServiceLocatorVsDependencyInjection). This quite makes sense if you have a lot of classes each depending on some repository; Constructor injection has no added value by making such dependency explicit, because it's already an obvious dependency.

Answer (score 1):

The first method is depending on a factory method (I hope). Inside this factory method an `IProgramRepository` is created. This function is not depending on anything but the factory method itself.

```
public static List<Program> GetProgramsByUser(int userId)
{
    return GetProgramsByUser(userId, GetDefaultRepository());
}
```

The second method is also not depending on an other class. The depencing is "given" in a parameter.

```
private static List<Program> GetProgramsByUser(int userId, IProgramRepository repo)
{
    return repo.GetProgramsByUser(userId);
}
```

**EDIT**

Officially Depenency Injection (DI) is a subset of Inversion of Control (IoC) and these terms are mixed up sometimes. Perhapse officially your code does not realy follow the rules of DI, but it is IoC for sure!