# Dependency injection for extension classes?

Tags: c#, .net, ioc-container

I'm using Microsoft Unity as my IoC container. I have a number of extension classes which adds useful methods to my business objects
This is the sort of code I use today:

```
public static class BusinessObjectExtensions
{
    public static bool CanDoStuff(this BusinessObject obj) 
    {
        var repository = BusinessHost.Resolver.Resolve<IRepository>();
        var args = new EArgument { Name = obj.Name };
        return repository.AMethod(obj.UserName, args);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to manage dependency injection for extension classes?

Comment: i think, It does not showing having any requirement to be an `extension method` .. so many dependency objects are their

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282223/implementing-dependency-injection-static-methods

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should actually try to avoid extensionmethods unless they only work on internal data (properties in the class itself), or simple datatypes provided in the method. You should not talk to other dependencies in your extension methods. If you follow this rule, you should not need to inject extension-classes with your IoC at all.

Comment: Example. I want to trim lengthy text before returning it. It's done by extension method. This method needs to know maximum length of the string and if trimming is enabled at all. In this case this knowledge is in configuration file. How would you approach this without passing all these as parameters to the Trim method?

Comment: @Mariusz you'd better pass that value. Optionally you can wrap it into a private method where you call it ;)

Comment: not internal but public data.

Comment: @Mariusz Why only extension method is the solution for your problem? You can also create a helper class and use it's injected object to perform the case.

Comment: @UmairTahir Yes, another service will also do. Extension method would be my first choice though as there is no need to inject extra services.

Comment: but you're still injecting a service to stop injecting a service :)

Answer (score 32):

The de facto default way of Dependency Injection by Constructor Injection is not possible for static classes. It would be possible to use Parameter Injection like below, however that is not a very clean way.

```
public static class BusinessObjectExtensions
{
    public static bool CanDoStuff(this BusinessObject obj, IRepository repository)
    {
        var args = new EArgument { Name = obj.Name };
        return repository.AMethod(obj.UserName, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The only way is method injection.

Comment: how can we have static variables, assigned using non-constructor because extension class does not have constructor?

Comment: @mnwsmit where did u assign repository? and where it is declared?

Comment: how to call this extension?

Answer (score 6):

Why would you do that?

This raises the coupling in your application to the roof and can be very confusing for your teammates to use the extension method (they'll have to keep in mind to inject the repository each time the method is used).

Instead, create a separate class and use constructor injection to inject the `IRepository` instance:

```
public class StuffExecuter    
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;

    public StuffExecuter(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(BusinessObject obj)
    {
        _repository.Add(obj.UserName, new EArgument
        {
            Name = obj.Name
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is how we do it by design, but the example above was taken from a really specific, if not entirely isolated, use case, wherein we believed in the convenience of hooking the functionality we needed to our business object. In hindsight, it wasn't a good idea, so I'll move it elsewhere. Thank you!

Comment: I would like to inject a logger to be able to log from an extension method.