# Dependency Injection inside a static class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I am working on existing code and need to rewrite or get dependency injection to work inside a static class. First, I don't want to write all static class in this project and pass the interface in the constructor. Is there a work around?

Here is what I have

```
public static class MyUserClass
    {
        private readonly IMyDBHelper  myDBHelper;

        public static string Get()
        {
         
             ....
            
        }
    }
```

When I  build, I get the error

> cannot declare instance members in a static class.

Thanks

Comment: Static classes are at the opposite end of the SOLID principles. You are not going to be able to easily get DI inside a static class (other than by receiving from parameters) and you shouldn't either.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52325438/how-to-inject-dependency-to-static-class

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282223/implementing-dependency-injection-static-methods