# Is there a way to inject into an extension?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

Recently I had something like this in my code:

```cs
public static void SomeExtension(this Entity obj, IA a, IB b)
{
  // implementation
  ...
}
```

I have registered the implementation for `IA` and `IB` using DI so ideally I want to be able to call

```cs
obj.SomeExtension();
```

rather than

```cs
class A
{
  private readonly IA _a;
  private readonly IB _b;

  public A(IA a, IB b)
  {
    // inject in constructor instead of inside an extension
    _a = a;
    _b = b;
  }

  ...

  public void SomeFunction(Entity obj)
  {
    obj.SomeExtension(_a, _b);
  }
}
```

I don't like the fact that `_a` and `_b` is only used in calling an extension and it's still necessary to inject it in a constructor. I would like the parameters to be injected automatically. Is it possible?

Comment: You can write a wrapper for `obj` that does much the same thing, but if `A` is already that wrapper, this is pretty much the right way to do it. You could apply anti-patterns like passing a service locator or other DI mechanism to A that allows it to resolve the call, but there is a reason such thing are anti-patterns -- they obscure dependencies, which is exactly what DI is supposed to solve. Look at your class `A` as providing a service  -- it can itself be registered as a dependency so at least `IEntity.SomeExtension` can become a thing.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282223/implementing-dependency-injection-static-methods